# Chef Opscode Using Value of Attribute in libraries file

Tags: templates, attributes, chef-infra, libraries, cookbook

I have to fetch the dnsdomainname value in my attribute file of my cookbook. Is there any possible way of doing this? Can i even fetch value from OHAI in my library file?

Comment: In an attribute file or library file? Because you mentioned both.

Answer (score 0):

In an attributes file `node['domainname']`. In a library file, it depends a lot on where and how your code works, but usually `Chef.node['domainname']`.

You can also always run `ohai | less` to see what data is available from Ohai.